# Rails group by query still return duplicate record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i've some query to select all data based on `skipped_play_id` but when i'm execute the query it still return some duplicate `skipped_play_id`

```
user = User.first     
skipped_plays=user.user_skipped_plays.select(:skipped_play_id,:created_at).group(:created_at,:skipped_play_id)
```

and why should i provide `:created_at` as one of group by argument if i only need query grouped by `skipped_play_id`. if i change my query to `user.user_skipped_plays.select(:skipped_play_id,:created_at).group(:skipped_play_id)`

it will return

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "user_skipped_plays.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  "user_skipped_plays"."skipped_play_id", "user_skippe...
                                                        ^
: SELECT  "user_skipped_plays"."skipped_play_id", "user_skipped_plays"."created_at" FROM "user_skipped_plays" WHERE "user_skipped_plays"."user_id" = $1 GROUP BY "user_skipped_plays"."skipped_play_id" ORDER BY "user_skipped_plays"."id" ASC LIMIT $2
from /Users/fourtyonestudio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:657:in `prepare
```

i'll really appreciate any advice

Comment: You need to define all the selected field in group by. like you selected `created_at` than you need to define it in group.

Comment: What you want with `skipped_play_id`, do you want any count of total fields ?

Comment: @Vishal i just want to extract the whole data `skipped_play_id` from table `user_skipped_plays` grouped by `skipped_play_id`  the table schema is `UserSkippedPlay(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, skipped_play_id: integer)`

Comment: you are grouping by `:skipped_play_id, :created_at` that is why it is returning duplicates. If you group it by `:skipped_play_id` only. It will not return duplicates but then you cannot have created_at in your query. Why do you need created at in your query in the first place? all the rows grouped by `:skipped_play_id` cannot have the same `created_at` that is why it is throwing the error message.

Comment: GROUP BY isn't for eliminating duplicates, it is for grouping rows for aggregate functions. Perhaps a bit of searching for "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need `GROUP BY` in your code at all. If you need to select unique rows containing just `skipped_play_id` and `created_at` you can go with:

```
user.user_skipped_plays.select(:skipped_play_id, :created_at).uniq
```

But in such selection you will still get duplicated `skipped_play_id` if you have different rows with same `skipped_play_id`, but different `created_at`, because you take a combination. So, possibly, you just need to go with:

```
user.user_skipped_plays.select(:skipped_play_id).uniq
```

It depends on what you need. You can type in comments for my answer how do you plan to use this selection and I will help you to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
User.first.user_skipped_plays.group_by { |t| t.skipped_play_id }
```

Let me know if you are getting correct data or not

Comment: Thanks for your advice